# Understanding how nameserver and apache works together

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, nameserver

I have a VPS from PHPWebhosting and use 1&1 to manage my domain names.  I can either set 1&1 to point to my VPS IP, or I can set 1&1 up to use PHPWebhosting's name servers, and then use PHPWebhosting's portal to create an "Extra Domain" and point it to my VPS IP.  Is one option better than the other?

I've always been told that it takes a while after making changes for my domain name to work.  What takes a while to update?  I added a new domain name to 1&1 yesterday.  This morning, I added a new Apache virtual host with the new domain name and pointed it to the correct directory.  I then went to 1&1, and pointed the domain name to my VPS IP. I then put the new domain name in my browser and it rendered the new page instantly.  What am I misunderstanding and what takes time to update?

Answer (score 1):

So I see two questions:

- Off Site DNS (1&1) vs. On Site DNS (PHPWebhosting)
- DNS Propagation time (Waiting for the domain to update)

First question, there is no conceptual difference between the two DNS services when managing your domain. However, in the real world redundancy and stability is key. 1&1 is a much larger company, and is therefore able to host multiple backup DNS servers, or DNS servers for different world regions (possibly closer to your target audience). 1&1 is also authorized to sell domains, this shows that they have a level of trust with the community. I recommend sticking with 1&1 and allow them to maintain your nameservers.

Second question, what you're talking about is DNS propagation or when the domain records are transferred to different DNS around the world. DNS is complex, so please take a look at this (http://support.powerdnn.com/KB/a604/dns-propagation-and-why-it-takes-so-long-explained.aspx) for a full expanation.

What you experienced (I added a new domain name to 1&1 yesterday. This morning, I added a new Apache virtual host) is not related to DNS propagation times advertised (as propagation takes < 6 hours). Your experience is due to DNS records have no effect on your server. In DNS you're telling the public Internet that a domain is at a certain location (IP address). Setting up an apache virtual host just makes the location public (which is instant).

Comment: Thanks Mark.  I realize that changing Apache should have no effect.  What I thought would have an effect is changing 1and1 to point to my VPS.  But now, I think it really is all the DNS needing to point to the correct nameserver (whether 1&1 or whatever) which takes time, and only the single (or clustered) nameserver needing to know to point to my VPS (which is quick). So when someone types www.mysite.com into their browser, they are never pointing directly to my VPS but only the namesever.  Is this how it works?  Thanks

Comment: Yes, then your Name Server (1&1) points the browser to your server's internet location or IP address. The reason why changing your DNS information takes time is that DNS servers (your ISP's, Google's, etc) create a cached copy of information (like Name Servers) for speed and lower bandwidth costs. You're most likely using these DNS services. So you're not waiting for an update on 1&1 - instead you're waiting until your DNS server gets a copy.

Answer (score 1):

Every DNS record has a duration attached to it that explains how long it is valid (and, thus, how long it can be cached by other DNS servers). So when you request the IP address for a name record, your local system or your own DNS server might cache the result and not update it until the specified duration has passed.

This leads to the statement that DNS changes can take X amount of time to show an effect.

If you have never before made a request for that given name, then it also isn't cached. This is especially true for the case when you've just registered a new domain name. In that case the request will always be passed to the master DNS server for your domain.